# Is there a way to "push" other clips in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a number of clips in the video editor, and I want to rearrange them.

Is there a way to grab and move a clip, so it'll push the other clips behind to make space for it?

E.g.: I want to rearrange clips ABC to ACB without the need to move B out of the way first, and to put it back in the end.

Change this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

**EDIT:** The "ABC to ACB" change is just an example. I have over 60 clips I need to completely rearrange.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "push". I answered based on your image example, but based on your edit it sounds like this doesn't work for your use case.. Could you clarify?

Comment: @gandalf3: Let's have V1,V2,V3,...,V60. I want to have V60 between V1 and V2. With your solution, I'd have to press Alt-Left 58 times. I'm hoping for something simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Expand to fit" option which is enabled by hitting <kbd>G</kbd> for grab and then you can hit <kbd>G</kbd> again to toggle "Expand to fit" permanently or hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> to use toggle it temporarily.

When you have three strips with the new one selected but not yet in your final row:

[image: Three strips]

Just hit <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and then <kbd>G</kbd> again and place it "over" the existing strips:

[image: Grab with "Expand to fit ON"]

Confirm with left mouse button (<kbd>LMB</kbd>) or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and there you have the strip inserted in between the two existing ones:

[image: Result]

Moving a single handle works with expand to fit as well (even though, the next strip is then moved and not trimmed in length).

Answer (score 6):

For your particular case you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> swap the selected strip with the nearest strip in the direction of the pressed arrowkey.

Answer (score 2):

To move a group at once, create a meta strip of the selected strips first, move them as suggested, then un-meta.